# Data recovery help requested

Tags: 17.04

I have installed ubuntu 17.04 along side ubuntu 17.10 now I am unable to check my data present in ubuntu 17.10, I have not formatted the partition still the data is not available, can anyone help me in this.

Thanks in Advance for the same.

Comment: Make a live USB and use extundelete

Comment: @NerdOfLinux and how is that done exactly?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122305/undelete-a-just-deleted-file-on-ext4-with-extundelete

Comment: I do not understand. If both are present side-by-side why can you not simply boot into the 17.10 partition? Or simply mount the partition? Or are you asking how to do these?

Comment: I am not getting dual boot option as well and not able to see the data as well, not sure data is present or got deleted, as there is some critical data and required to be recovered.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand it's a rookie question, so here's how you do it:

Open Terminal CTRL+ALT+T

```
> sudo su                           #elevate to root
> fdisk -l                          #list all disks and partitions, find the one your files are on.
> mkdir /mnt/my_files               # make a new mount point
> mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt/my_files     # mount your partition eg: sdb2
> cd /mnt/my_files                  # change location to mount point
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but not working out, I have partition of 442 gb from which i am seeing 420 gb available. So rest 22gb data I am unable to see but it is present on the hard disk, please suggest how to look at that data.